# Azure pipeline building image from wrong Dockerfile

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile

My project contains 2 Dockerfiles, one for the backend and one for a mock database. I have a build pipeline in Azure using the following script:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: './MyProject'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    flattenFolders: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: './MyProject/Database'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/Database'
    flattenFolders: true

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'backend'
```

I put 2 CopyFiles steps in there because I have 2 Dockerfiles, one in /MyProject for the backend and one in /MyProject/Database for a mock database. This way I can choose between both Dockerfiles later on in my release pipeline. In the picture below I have one Dockerfile marked in the backend folder and you can see the other Dockerfile in the Database folder.

[image]

The problem is that even though I select the Dockerfile placed in the backend folder for the release step, the pipeline uses the Dockerfile for the database. Presumably this is because this is the first Dockerfile it encounters, even though it is located in a subdirectory of what I have specified. How can I make my pipeline use the correct Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: setting flattenFolders: true did so that the Dockerfile in the subdirectory overwrote the top-level Dockerfile. By setting it to false I got the complete folder structure and could choose the correct Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members to search this useful information more easily, it just a reminder :)